# set position of layout dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, dynamic, position

I want to create 4 RelativeLayout dynamically so that each subsequent layout is placed below the previous one. I'm trying to do this whit this piece of code:

```
RelativeLayout layoutParent = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutParent);
    int layouts = 4;

        int dp15 = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 15, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(dp15, dp15, dp15, dp15);


        for (int l = 0; l <= layouts; l++)
        {
            RelativeLayout queueLayout = new RelativeLayout(getApplicationContext());
            TextView one = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            one.setText(String.valueOf(l));
            queueLayout.setId(2000 + l);
            if (l != 0) params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, queueLayout.getId() - 1);
            queueLayout.addView(one, params);
            layoutParent.addView(queueLayout);
        }
```

But I can't get the desired position of each layout. Can someone tell me how can I do what I wanna do?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the `BELLOW` rule but never use it when you add the child `RelativeLayout` to the parent layout(as MisterSquonk said). Also use another set of `LayoutParams` for the child `RelativeLayout`:

```
for (int l = 0; l <= layouts; l++) {
        RelativeLayout queueLayout = new RelativeLayout(getApplicationContext());
        TextView one = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        one.setText(String.valueOf(l));
        queueLayout.setId(2000 + l);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        if (l != 0) lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, queueLayout.getId() - 1);
        queueLayout.addView(one, params);
        layoutParent.addView(queueLayout, lp);
    }
```

Comment: @KrLx_roller Do the `TextView`s overlap?

Comment: Yes, that's what is happening every time I execute the app

Comment: @KrLx_roller I've tested my code and it does work, the `TextView`s appear correctly(my parent `RelativeLayout`). Are you adding other elements that you didn't post in the code?

Comment: No, the TextView is the only element that I'm adding to the layout... It's very strange... I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: I've restarted Eclipse and voilá, working like a charm! Damn Eclipse... Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @KrLx_roller As a said I've tested the code and it worked so it was very strange. Eclipse has the bad habit to do this kind of stuff(and many more) from time to time.